# MongoDB c# create role?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm trying to create a role with the c# driver.
Can anyone please tell me how to do this?

I tried several things like this:

```
var command = new CommandDocument( 
                new BsonDocument
                {
                    { "createRole", "Testentity_read" },
                    { "privileges", new BsonArray(new BsonDocument
                        {
                            {
                                "resource", new BsonDocument
                                {
                                    {"db", "MyDb"},
                                    {"collection", "Testentity"}
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "actions", new BsonArray {"read"}
                            }
                        })},
                    { "roles", new BsonArray()}
                }
            );

            var result = _database.RunCommand(command);
```

but always getting this exception:

```
".NET type MongoDB.Bson.BsonElement cannot be mapped to a BsonValue."
```

Comment: here is what I try to do: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/define-roles/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to create a role from C#-driver.

```
var command = new CommandDocument
{
    {
        "createRole", "Testentity_find"
    },
    { 
        "privileges", new BsonArray
        {
            new BsonDocument
            {
                {
                   "resource", new BsonDocument
                    {
                        {"db", "MyDb"},
                        {"collection", "Testentity"}
                    }
                },
                {

                    "actions", new BsonArray {"find"}
                }
            }
        }
    },
    { "roles", new BsonArray()}
};
```